# Why does passing a list to subset a data frame return another data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My question is simple.

```
df[[‘column’]]
```

Will return a data frame object but

```
df[‘column’]
```

Will return a series object.
My question is just why it behaves like this. Is this just a behavior inherent to the code running under the hood? Or was this a choice with specific reasoning behind it? Is it convention in other languages? I’ve been learning pandas for about 6 months now, it’s fairly intuitive, but I’ve always wondered why pandas behaves this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `columns = [‘column1’, 'column2']`, `df[columns]` returns a dataframe with two columns.

So (for coherence reasons), if `columns = [‘column1’]`, `df[columns]` returns a dataframe with one column.

Whereas if `column = 'column1'` (not a list), `df[column]` returns a series